# How to control the distortion level of the google reCaptcha image gem for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, recaptcha

I am using the rails recaptach gem https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha

The default image that comes is very highly distorted and I would like to make it a little simpler to read. Is there a way that we could control the distortion level of the image that is shown up? any configuration options available in the gem. I have asked the same question as well, however, have not got any reply yet.

Also, if we can control the number of text items that appear. By default its 2, can we control it to make it one instead via this gem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The recaptcha gem is a wrapper around the the reCAPTCHA library itself, so you're very much limited by what that library offers in the way of customisation. The gem can't expose elements for customisation that aren't supported by the underlying library.

As you'll see from the documentation at https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization, customisation is pretty much confined to the visual appearance around the CAPTCHA codes – you can't customise the code appearance themselves.

If the reCAPTCHA style isn't to your taste, it's possible that there are other forms of reverse Turing test that will be more to your liking.